# How to separate values from the range funcion with a "+" as they're printed?

Tags: python, printing

I am new to python and i'm stuck on a simple task. I want to print a range of number on the same line, with a "+" between each of them. This is the best I've been able to do so far, but obviously there is an extra "+" at the end of my line.

```
for i in range (1,10):
    print (i , end="+")
```

Output:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple one-line solution:

```
result = "+".join(str(i) for i in range(1, 10))
```

You can use the built-in [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to insert a delimiter between each item in a list. In this case, the delimiter is +. We pass the iterable generated by `range` as the argument, converting each number into a string via the looping construct.

**EDIT:** If you need to use iteration for this, I'd go with the following approach:

```
result = ""
for i in range(1, 10):
    result += str(i) + "+"
print(result[:-1])
```

Basically we create an empty string, append each number and a + sign to it, and then remove the last character using the slice.

If you cannot use *anything* list-related, then the easiest approach would be to stop the loop before the final number and add it manually.

```
result = ""
for i in range(1, 9):
    result += str(i) + "+"
print(result + "9")
```

Comment: A common pattern I've adopted for concatenating potential non-strings is: `'+'.join(map(str, iterable))` .. which is more efficient for large sets than constructing list comprehension. (out of scope for beginner question)

Comment: @blakev `join` has to fully instantiate the list to determine the size of the result anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your great anwser, However i forgot to say but i can't use list for this problem

Comment: @JeffPetry Check out the edit. I added a few additional ways using iteration.

Comment: @chepner a naive list comprehension is the slowest way to build strings in Python. See: [comprehensive tests](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/), [quick and simple](https://gist.github.com/blakev/250633fb7a8d148c6594684c097f13cb#file-map_join_str-py)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to print the values, you could [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the sequence returned by `range()` and pass a custom separator to [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
>>> print(*range(1, 10), sep="+")                     
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9
```

Comment: Yes i only have to print, but there are some condition between my range function and my print, so it does'nt seem to work this way

Answer (score 0):

Shortest and arguably most-readable snippet I can think of:

```
print('+'.join(map(str, range(1, 10))))  # -> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9
```